# How can I generate a page that will always contain a list all the pages (not posts)?

Tags: sitemap

I want to have a list of all the articles in my WP website, so it will be updated each time a new one is added. How can I do this? And how can I include it in my home page?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/query-loop-block/ is one approach using blocks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new page template and use the function wp_list_pages on that page. This will help you generate links to all pages present on your WordPress site.